# How do I check if nested keys exist in json?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have the folowing `if` statement which works fine:

```
if (json1.ContainsKey("key2"))
{
    // do something here.
}
```

`json1` contains the following:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "key1_1": "value1_1",
    "key1_2": "value1_2",
    "key1_3": [
      "value1_3_2",
      "value1_3_2"
    ],
    "key1_1": "value1_1"
  },
  "key2": "value2_1",
  "key3": "value3_1"
}
```

I can get specific values from the keys like this:

1. `console.writeline(json1["key2"]);`
2. `console.writeline(json1["key1"]["key1_3"][0]);`

I am now trying to check if `key1_3` exists, but don't know how to.

I have tried the following code examples and they do not work:

```
if (json1.ContainsKey("key1_3"))
{
    // do something here.
}

if (json1["key1"].ContainsKey("key1_3"))
{
    // do something here.
}
```

How do I check if a nested key exists such as `key1_3`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ContainsKey` is method defined on [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ContainsKey.htm) while indexer [returns `JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm). You can use [json path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), `SelectToken` and check it for `null`:

```
var token = json1.SelectToken("$.key1.key1_3");
if(token != null)  
{
    ....
}
```

Or like this:

```
if(json1["key1"]?["key1_3"] != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want check key you can use:

```
if(json1["key1"].Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    if(json1["key1"].Value<JObject>().ContainsKey("key1_3"))
    {
        /// TODO
    }
}
```